# What is ping6: sendto: Permission denied a sign of when debugging?

Tags: ipv6, openwrt

I'm trying to understand why some IPv6 requests (not all) seem to return permission denied errors when using tools like ping6, traceroute, curl etc.

I have a secondary WAN connection configured on a router running OpenWrt which has IPv4 and IPv6 connectivity, when pinging certain IPv6 addresses (v4 is fine) I get:

`ping6: sendto: Permission denied`

However, for other IPv6 addresses they work fine, one example that works is ipv6.google.com, but dns.google over v6 doesn't. However there is IPv6 connectivity as confirmed by working IPv6 sites. I initially thought firewall, but I don't understand why some IPv6 sites work fine and others don't.

I am confused as to why a seemingly random list of sites return permission denied and others are fine. The same occurs with literal IPv6 addresses as well.

What is the sendto: Permission denied error referring to exactly?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be specific to OpenWrt and IPv6 source address selection in various scenarios. I came across several references around the issue:

- https://forum.openwrt.org/t/ipv6-source-address-selection-broken-for-packets-generated-on-the-router/37303
- https://forum.openwrt.org/t/ping-and-traceroute-failing-for-eth0-3-on-ipv6/44680
- https://forum.openwrt.org/t/ipv6-source-address-selection-broken-for-packets-generated-on-the-router/37303

There also seems to be issues with Busybox ping vs iputils-ping packages, it appears to be broken currently.